# how to get json data from php file in angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a php file which returns a json data. I am using angular http ajax.
But I am unable to get my properly formatted json which i want to use in my angular js. Please have a look at my code:

file name: json.php

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data1 = array('name' => 'dheerendra', 'city' => 'bangalore');
$data2 = array('name' => 'kk', 'city' => 'delhi');
$data3 = array('name' => 'aakash', 'city' => 'kanpur');
$data4 = array('name' => 'amit', 'city' => 'bangkok');

$data[] = [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4];
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

this is my app.js file for angular js:

filename: app.js

```
var calculator = angular.module('calculator', ['ngRoute', 'myController']);

calculator.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
    var customers = [];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getCustomers = function () {
       return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/json.php'}).
                then(function successCallback(response) {
                    customers = response.data;
                    return customers;
                });
    };
    return factory;
});
```

this is my angular controller:

filename: controller.js

```
var myController = angular.module('myController', []);

myController.controller('controller1', function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
    $scope.customers = [];
    init();
    function init() {
        var myDataPromise = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
        myDataPromise.then(function (result) {
            // this is only run after getData() resolves
            $scope.customers = result;
            console.log($scope.customers );
        });
    }
});
```

this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="calculator">
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="controller1">            
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="customer in customers">
             {{customer.name}} - {{customer.city}}
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/app.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my console.log($scope.customers ) shows this :

Ok I saw that I have the data in console.log but how do I get those values which I am interested in ?

[image]

I want my customer array to have only these values so that I can print them in my li element:

```
var customer=[          
          {name: 'dheerendra', city: 'bangalore'},
          {name: 'kk', city: 'delhi'},
          {name: 'aakash', city: 'kanpur'},
          {name: 'amit', city: 'bangkok'},
        ];
```

I have created another same array in the file and I am logging both the arrays. Both of them seems to be different:

```
var myController = angular.module('myController', []);

myController.controller('controller1', function ($scope, simpleFactory) {
    $scope.customers = [];
    init();
    function init() {
        //$scope.customers = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
        var myDataPromise = simpleFactory.getCustomers();
        myDataPromise.then(function (result) {
            // this is only run after getData() resolves
            $scope.customers1 = [
                {name: 'dheerendra', city: 'bangalore'},
                {name: 'kk', city: 'delhi'},
                {name: 'aakash', city: 'kanpur'},
                {name: 'amit', city: 'bangkok'}
            ];
            $scope.customers = result;
            console.log($scope.customers1);
            console.log($scope.customers);
        });
    }
});
```

console output is as follows:

[image]

Top one is my hardcoded array and bottom one is what I got from http.
Both of them seem to be different.

Found the solution. The problem was in my json.php file

```
$data[] = [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4] ;
```

this line was creating an array of length one which contained array of four objects. Thats why `customers = response.data;` was not returning me those 4 objects.

The solution is to just remove square brackets  in this line

```
$data = [$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4];
```

Comment: so whats the actual issue here? seems you have the data, is just the outputting it an issue?

Comment: Yes I have the data but I don't know how to get only the data which I am interested in .

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: which data are you interested in bro? :)

Comment: actually I am printing the name and city values in list item, but my list item is empty.

Comment: try to change the .then in the factory to .success

Comment: @user2950720 `.success` is deprecated. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console log. The XHR is returning an array of length one that contains an array of four objects.

Modify your factory to handle that.

```
calculator.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
    var customers = [];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getCustomers = function () {
       return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'data/json.php'}).
                then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //Use This
                    customers = response.data[0];
                    //Instead of this
                    //customers = response.data;
                    return customers;
                });
    };
    return factory;
});
```